# Aes Decrypt goes wrong when using GET - PHP

Tags: php, aes

Aes Decrypt goes wrong when I using GET method.

```
resetPassword.php?em=/7tI2cvhU31O0v3Dr+YGtpgPaxKVB6InHeriyZhxyNk=
```

this is what I send to php file, if I print the: `$_GET['em']`
the page show me this output: /7tI2cvhU31O0v3Dr+YGtpgPaxKVB6InHeriyZhxyNk=

this is ok,
if I call to decrypt function like: `fnDecrypt($_GET['em'], $AESPassword)`
I get this output: ����H�M�.�Ҭ�;��&4o�r0�V`jڔݖ�

if I call decrypt function like: `fnDecrypt("/7tI2cvhU31O0v3Dr+YGtpgPaxKVB6InHeriyZhxyNk=", $AESPassword)`

I get the correct output, so can anyone tell me where is the problem ?

my AES functiob for encrypt and decrypt:

```
  $iv = "d7e45c64ecb7c5eebdb9af404c0c9eff";
  function fnEncrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey) {
    global $iv;
    return rtrim(
         base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt(
               MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
               $sSecretKey, $sValue,
               MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv)),
               "\0\3");
  }

  function fnDecrypt($sValue, $sSecretKey) {
    global $iv;
    return rtrim(
        mcrypt_decrypt(
           MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
           $sSecretKey, base64_decode($sValue),
           MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv),
           "\0\3");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't get that plus sign that is in your URL, because that is a special character in URLs that represents a space character (hex 20, dec 32). The equal sign also has a special meaning.

And if the original sign was indeed a plus, the decryption fails because it's the wrong code.

You are likely not encoding that URL correctly. Note that every value that goes into the query string of a URL, both key and value, must be URL encoded. Use `urlencode()` or `rawurlencode()` for this.

Also note that every URL that goes into HTML has to be HTML encoded: `htmlspecialchars()`.

Two more things: I'm pretty sure your encryption now is broken because you published more details than you should about your encryption scheme.

And I do wonder why you'd need to encrypt something when resetting a password inside the URL.

Comment: Yes you right, I don't get the + sign, and I also the get it with urlencode() or rawurlencode() .. I try this: str_replace(" ","+",$_GET['em']) and it is work, but what more sign should I need to replace ?

Comment: Don't implement urlencoding yourself, that's what these functions are about. Encode where you create that link. When you get it back, nothing needs to be done.